# How can I remove all Non-Alphabetic characters from a String using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove all non-alphabetic characters from a String.

*Input*:

```
"-Hello, 1 world$!"
```

Output:

```
"Helloworld"
```

But instead I'm getting: `"Hello1world"`

How can I fix it?

*My code:*

```
public class LabProgram {
    public static String removeNonAlpha (String userString) {
    String[] stringArray = userString.split("\\W+");
        String result = new String();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length;i++){
            result = result+ stringArray[i];
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scnr.nextLine();
        String result = removeNonAlpha(str);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code. Formatting matters as you want folks to be able to quickly and easily read and understand your code and question.

Comment: You're using \W to split non-word character, but word characters are defined as alphanumeric plus underscore https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static String removeNonAlpha (String userString) {
        // If you only want to remove the characters A to Z (lower an uppercase)
        //return userString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
        return userString.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]+", "");
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scnr.nextLine();
        String result = removeNonAlpha(str);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: \p{alpha} is preferable, since it gets all alphabetic characters, not just A to Z (and a to z)

Comment: @passer-by thanks i did not know something like this exists - changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), which expects a regular expression as the first argument and a replacement-string as a second:

```
return userString.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]", "");
```

[*for more information on regular expressions take a look at this tutorial*](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your regex pattern is matching more than just letters, but also matching numbers and the underscore character, as that is what `\W` does.  Replacing this fixes the issue:

```java
String[] stringArray = userString.split("\\P{Alpha}+");
```

Per the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) Javadocs, `\W` matches any non-word character, where a word character is defined in `\w` as `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.  This means that it matches upper and lowercase ASCII letters A - Z & a - z, the numbers 0 - 9, and the underscore character ("_").

The solution would be to use a regex pattern that excludes only the characters you want excluded.  Per the pattern documentation could do `[^a-zA-Z]` or `\P{Alpha}` to exclude the main 26 upper and lowercase letters.  If you want to count letters other than just the 26 ASCII letters (e.g. letters in non-Latin alphabets), you could use `\P{IsAlphabetic}`.

> `\p{`*`prop`*`}` matches if the input has the property *prop*, while `\P{`*`prop`*`}` does not match if the input has that property.

As other answers have pointed out, there are other issues with your code that make it non-idiomatic, but those aren't affecting the correctness of your solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between `\\P` and `\\p`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 public static String removeNonAlpha (String userString) {
    return userString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+",  "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\W` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, so it include numerics caracters.

Just replace it by `"[^a-zA-Z]+"`, like in the below example :

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "-Hello, 1    world$!";
        System.out.println("Input : " + input);
        String[] split = input.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Arrays.stream(split).forEach(builder::append);
        System.out.println("Ouput :" + builder);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Input : -Hello, 1    world$!
Ouput :Helloworld
```

You can have a look at this article for more details about regular expressions :
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#meta-characters